# d3 interaction between xAxis and text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a problem that it is cause by the interaction of a `g' axis element and a series of`text` elements. I am trying to build a graph with only a date x axis where squares are positioned along the correspondent date x coordinate but at the same y.

The code I am working on is the following:

```
var dataset = [

            {'startYear' : '2004-01-12',
            'label' : 'green'},
            {'startYear' : '2005-06-07',
            'label' : 'red'},
            {'startYear' : '2010-03-04',
            'label' : 'red'},
            {'startYear' : '2010-07-28',
            'label' : 'yellow'}

          ];

          var w = 750;
          var h = 500;
          var padding = 30;


          var svg = d3.select(element[0])
                      .append('svg')
                      .attr('width',w)
                      .attr('height',h);

          var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                        .domain([new Date('2004-01-01'),new Date('2014-12-31')])
                        .range([padding,w-padding*2]);

          var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(xScale)
                        .orient('bottom')
                        .ticks(d3.time.years)
                        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y'));


          var axisStyle = {'fill': 'none', 'stroke': 'black','shape-rendering': 'crispEdges','font-family':'sans-serif','font-size': '11px'};

          svg.append('g')
                .style(axisStyle)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
                .call(xAxis);

          svg.selectAll('rect')
             .data(dataset)
             .enter()
             .append('rect')
             .attr('x',function(d){return xScale(new Date(d.startYear));})
             .attr('y',h-padding*2.5)
             .attr('height',20)
             .attr('width',20)
             .attr('fill',function(d){return d.label;});

          svg.selectAll('text')
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x',0)
            .attr('y',30)
            .text('monkeys');
```

For some reasons the `text` elements are not rendered on the screen. When investigating the causes of the problem, I found out that commenting out the `g` element for the x axis is a solution but obviously I need to keep to xaxis. Why is this happening? And is there a solution around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the axes first. That means that by the time you run the code to add the labels, there are already `text` elements in the DOM. Therefore, `svg.selectAll('text')` selects them. Then D3 matches the data you pass to `.data()` to them and finds a match for each data item. Hence, the `.enter()` selection is empty.

To fix, assign a special class to these labels that allows you to distinguish them from the other `text` elements:

```
svg.selectAll('text.label')
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr('x',0)
        .attr('y',30)
        .text('monkeys');
```